# How to figure the wiring of a 4 cable pc fan without frying it?

Tags: measurement, wiring

I have a 2 spare PC Fans which come with a four cable wiring and I would like to reuse them as ordinary fans (running at full speed all the time) outside a PC box, powered by a 12v source.

Unfortunately the wires have all the same color, so there is no way of guessing what is what. Is there a way I can "measure out" (using a multimeter) the correct connections?

Update: Thanks to the comments I figured out where plus and minus is and the fan is running. But although I can't be sure, to me it seems that it is not running at full speed. What would I have to feed into the remaining two cables to have it run at max power?

And I forgot to mention, that I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: Is the connector still attached? There is a standard to 4 pin motherboard fan connectors.

Comment: You can try to "measure out", but it is better to start with Google for [4-wire PC fan connector].

Comment: Anyone designs an unkeyed connector with same colour wires ought to have reverse polarity protection included or it’s a junk design. Use a 33 to 100 ohm in series using pin 1,4 and test it safely The other pins may be RPM tach and PWM input?  Or a DMM 1A scale and pulse it. Expect <0.3A approx

Comment: @WesleyLee: Yes it was attached and I found the pinning using google. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thank you for your help, but at least half of vocabulary you used is some sort of chinese for me... I should have probably mentioned that I'm a bloody beginner in the first place.

Comment: Re: your update: if it’s a standard PC fan, it should be designed to run full speed without any other connections.

Comment: @Mats then that is not Tony's fault, if you don't mention that then using "standard" jargon is fair...

Comment: even google has a chinese translator  https://www.google.ca/search?q=+RPM+tach+and+PWM+input%3F+Or+a+DMM&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=67-VWuyGFuXj8Ae0paGwAQ

Comment: next one over is a speed sensor, other end from DC is PWM in.